# Passing Xcolor package in YAML markdown for Pandoc

Tags: color, pandoc

I have the following YAML in a `.md` file and everything is working smooth.
But I want to use `xcolor` to change color for TOC.

Pandoc Manual ([see here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#links)) says:

> linkcolor, filecolor, citecolor, urlcolor, toccolor
>
> color for internal links, external links, citation links, linked URLs, and links in table of contents, respectively: `uses options allowed by xcolor, including the dvipsnames, svgnames, and x11names lists`

My Question is: how do I pass xcolor option / or how to use `svgnames` color, because if I change
`toccolor: Blue` to `toccolor: DarkBlue` I get undefined color.

```
Error producing PDF.
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `DarkBlue'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Here is the YAML Code

```yaml
---
title: Name of the Article
author: Author Name
date: \today
lang: ro-RO
geometry:
  - a4paper
  - margin=2.5cm
  - heightrounded
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[L]{\textbf{\leftmark}}
  \fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\rightmark}}
  \lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}
numbersections: yes,
linestretch: 1.2
toccolor: Blue
bibliography: [X:/absolute/path/to/ref.bib]
csl: [X:/absolute/path/to/chicago-fullnote-bibliography.csl]
documentclass: article
toc: true
---
```

Comment: There are some solutions discussed at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6109. If that helps you to solve the issue then you can post the solution here as a self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Marijn suggested by pointing to Github there is an issue with the `default.latex` template, meaning that instead of

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
```

currently, template has:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*}{xcolor}
```

Pandoc version `2.13` has this issue, but the template is fixed on GitHub therefore will be shipped with the next version

#### In Windows 10

Solution for this problem is the following:

1. in command line

```
pandoc -D latex > default.latex
```

This will copy the template in the current directory.

2. remove `*` from `svgnames` and `x11names` in the line `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*}{xcolor}`
3. copy the modified `default.latex` to `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pandoc\templates`

   - if the directory not exists you have to create it.
4. run as ussualy: `pandoc INPUT.md -o OUTPUT.pdf`

`Thanks a lot, @Marijn!`